# Layouts in Rails for XML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

How do I use layouts with XML in Ruby on Rails? When using HTML a file `application.html.erb` with a `<%= yield %>` is enough, but that didn't work for XML. A file named `application.xml.builder` gets executed, but the `yield` doesn't work (without `<%= %>` of course). What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to append the result of the yield to output being produced.  Here's an example `application.xml.builder` that demonstrates this technique:

```
xml.header do
  xml << yield
end
```